# Drupal images in content break when migrating from local to server

Tags: drupal

I'm developing a site locally using xampp. The path the images are using is

/devsite/sites/default/files/icon_facebook.jpg

When I check out of the site on my server the path remains the same for the images, even though the image is now at

/~devsite/sites/default/files/icon_facebook.jpg

Are the image URLs just hard-coded by the wysiwyg including the wrong base path? Is there something I can do to make them work?

Comment: which version of drupal are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using wysiwyg, the image path is saved along with the rest of the HTML, and the filters don't convert it.  So under some conditions - especially if you're moving from a subdirectory to the HTML root - you'll have images that are misplaced.

The [pathologic module](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) might be of some help here.  Otherwise you could use Views Bulk Operations to do a `string_replace()` operation your HTML fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the $base_url in sites/default/settings.php.  I'm not sure how the WYSIWYG is setting images, but it's pretty standard that it should be using a path relative to the base url.